# Model setData dateTime field set current date

Tags: magento2, date

I have an extension attribute for a dateTime field in `sales_order` table.

What I want to do on a certain action is to set the value of this field to `NOW()`.

How can I perform this?

```
$order->setData('my_date_time_field', WHAT_SHOULD_I_WROTE_HERE?);
```

Now I am using the Magento stdLib\DateTime class to get the data, I just want sql to use it's own `NOW()` function.

Comment: you can try php `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: Did my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262587/76597 help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `Zend_Db_Expr` object. The following code should creat the MySQL statement the way you want:

```
$order->setData('my_date_time_field', new \Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
```

I hope that helps, feedback would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` in Constructor and use it's instance to get current date as below:

`$this->_date->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

**Note:** I have created $_date instance for TimezoneInterface